# Where is source code for git hosted ? Is it at github or some other sites?

Tags: git

The [git-scm](https://git-scm.com) website says that it's at [github](https://github.com/git/git) under the download section.

However [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git) says it's at [git.kernel.org](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git). There's also corresponding clone links in that site.

Comment: Well, both sites host the same source code. AFAIK, git.kernel.org is the official one, while GitHub hosts a mirror.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

https://git.kernel.org is correct, specifically https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/.

https://github.com/git/git has "About" text that indicates it is a mirror:

> Git Source Code Mirror - This is a publish-only repository but pull requests can be turned into patches to the mailing list via GitGitGadget (https://gitgitgadget.github.io/).

`git-scm.com` seems to be only semi-official: It's linked from the source tree's README but per the [About this site](https://git-scm.com/site) link at the bottom, git-scm is an open-source third-party piece of documentation that became the Pro Git book (advertised in the left column). Since the [official repo](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/) is based on `cgit` and is relatively minimal in its UI, I imagine GitHub and git-scm are more welcoming to newcomers and thus more popular.

Comment: I see. But there wasn't any mention of the official one in github or in the official website (git-scm).

Comment: @RaZ0rr True. I don't have a good reason that it's not linked directly from GitHub. That said, `git-scm.com` seems to be only semi-official: It's linked from the source tree's README but per the [About this site](https://git-scm.com/site) link at the bottom, git-scm is an open-source third-party piece of documentation that became the Pro Git book (advertised in the left column). Since the [official repo](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/) is based on `cgit` and is relatively minimal in its UI, I imagine GitHub and git-scm are more welcoming to newcomers and thus more popular.